# Using version specific scala compiler options

Tags: scala, sbt

I am looking at [Scala Compiler Options](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html). This doc explains all the compiler options in detail. But, this doc doesn't seem to be targeted for a specific scala version.

Does it mean it all the options are supported/recommended for all versions ?

Is there any `official documentation` which defines these compiler options with respect to a `particular scala version` ?

Would be really helpful to know the correct references to use for selecting these compiler options.

Comment: You might want to check out the list of recommended flags, this is obviously the list of all flags but this is helpful as well: https://nathankleyn.com/2019/05/13/recommended-scalac-flags-for-2-13/

Answer (score 3):

Print standard options

`scalac -help`

Print advanced options

`scalac -X`

Print private options

`scalac -Y`

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks :) And also found that `scalac -W` is for **Print Warning options**